# How do I split a string in multiple places using an integer array instead of a regex?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

If I have a string:

```
String s = "This is a string to test splitting on!";
```

And an array of integers representing indices within the string:

```
int[] indices = {4, 6, 9, 12, 15};
```

Is it possible to get an array of String like:

```
"This",
" i",
"s a",
" st",
"rin",
"g to test splitting on!"
```

without looping through the indices calling `s.substring(indices[i], indices[i+1])` (or similar)?

Unfortunately the indices are all arbitrary, so a regular expression won't help.  Basically I want to find an equivalent of split() where I can pass an integer array instead of a regex.

Comment: There is none. You'll have to write it yourself, but it sounds like you have a good-enough idea of how to go about that.

Comment: Yea... I was hoping there would be a way that had already been tested for efficiency :(

Comment: `String#substring()` is constant time. You're fine.

Comment: if you wanna write a method yourself , then why cant you use substring method ?? why avoiding it ??

Comment: There couldn't be a faster way than looping and using substring.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you don't want to use substring():

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringSplitter implements Iterable<String>
{
    private Scanner scanner;
    private StringBuilder toParse;
    private int indices[];

    public StringSplitter(String toSplit, int... indices)
    {
        Arrays.sort(indices);    //make sure it is sorted otherwise it won't work properly
        toParse = new StringBuffer(toSplit);
        for(int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i)
        {
            toParse.insert(indices[i] + i, "\u0080");
        }
        scanner = new Scanner(toParse.toString());
        scanner.useDelimeter("\u0080");
        this.indices = indices;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator()
    {
        return scanner;
    }
}
```

Then use the for-each loop to traverse the string:

```
StringSplitter s = new StringSplitter("This is a string to test splitting on!", 4, 6, 9, 12, 15);
for(String elem : s)
{
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```